# How can I use 11ty to generate one page per json file in _data subfolders?

Tags: eleventy

I'm trying to use 11ty to generate pages for a movie review site. The structure of my _data folder is as follows.

```
_data
  movies
    2017
      title1.json
      title2.json
    2018
    2019
```

I'm hoping for output like this.

```
_site
  movies
    2017
      title-1.html
      title-2.html
    2018
```

I would settle for output like this.

```
_site
  movies
    title-1.html
    title-2.html
```

But I can't work out how to get anything close! Any ideas? Here's my nunjucks template. `TitleWithYear` is a property in each .json file.

```
---
pagination:
    data: movies
    size: 1
    alias: movie
    resolve: keys
permalink: "movies/{{ year??? }}/{{ movie.TitleWithYear | slug }}/index.html"
---
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ movie.TitleWithYear }}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit: here's a repo showing the problem.

https://github.com/edmondbramhall/11ty-test1

Without the permalink line in, it does work although not with my desired folder structure in the output.

Edit: with Luke's help here's the pagination property I ended up with.

```
  permalink: "movies/{{ movie.ReleaseYear }}/{{ movie.Id }}-{{ movie.Title | slug }}/index.html"
```

I also created a global filter for slugify to supply a couple of settings by creating a file `.eleventy.js` in the root folder of my project, with the following content.

```
const slugify = require('slugify');
module.exports = function(eleventyConfig) {
    eleventyConfig.addFilter("slug", function(value) {
        return slugify(value, { strict: true, lower: true });
    });
};
```

Comment: Does the pagination code you have provided above work so far?

Comment: Can you send an example repro so I can have a fiddle locally?

Comment: Also it is usually worth trying to log your data before fiddling with pagination, so you have an easier overview of what you're working with. Can you put `{{ movie | log}}` and then `{{ movies | log}}` in your template and then post the resultant console logs here?

Comment: Thanks @LukeStorry - that code doesn't work, because slug complains that it's not being passed anything. Cheers for the tip on log. That shows an object with multiple keys, each key being the file name without extension (and therefore would do fine for output folder name). So that gives me hope I can get what I want, I'm just not sure how! Repo added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `data: movies` in your pagination, but the way that eleventy will try to deal with your given `data` folder structure is to make a list of objects per year folder, then each json file as a child JS object, with the filename as the key:

```
> console.log(data.movies)

[
  {
    'An-American-Tail_1986_4978': {
      ...
      TitleWithYear: 'An American Tail (1986)',
      Tagline: 'Meet Fievel. In his search to find his family, he discovered America.',
      ...
    },
    'Barbra-Streisand-One-Voice_1986_31683': {
      ...
      TitleWithYear: 'Barbra Streisand: One Voice (1986)',
      Tagline: 'Barbra sings in her backyard for charity!',
      ...
    }
  },

  {
    'Alien-Predators_1985_52318': {
      ...
      TitleWithYear: 'Alien Predators (1985)',
      ...
    }
  }
]
```

To get the data into a format such that eleventy can paginate it properly, you need to munge it into a single large array of objects. The [`before`](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/pagination/#the-before-callback) callback functionality of eleventy is by far the easiest way of doing that (also possible via changing your data file structure, or by creating a custom collection in config).

This does require your frontmatter to be in a `js` format instead, but allows you to map for the actual movie objects and then flatten the resultant array.

Below is a full working example of the `movie.njk` file from your example repo.

```
---js
{
  pagination:{
    data: "movies",
    before: (data) => data.map(year => Object.values(year)).flat(),
    size: 1,
    alias: "movie",
},
  permalink: "movies/{{ movie.Id }}/",
}
---
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ movie.TitleWithYear }}</h1>
    <p> {{ movie.Tagline}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Luke! You've nailed it here. It took me a while to be sure because (a) I had an error from the flat() method, due to needing to upgrade my local node version, and (b) with the full dataset I kept getting "undefined" coming back in the permalink when I put {{ movie.Title | slug }} back in. It turns out that was because some of the items in the dataset didn't have title values. The error message from 11ty doesn't give any indication of partial success generating the pages!

Comment: for debugging, you can extend the `before` callback into a larger multiline function, and then console log a few times in there - that can help!

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround for structure:

```
_data
  movies.js
movies
  title1.json
  title2.json
  title3.json
movie.njk
```

use [javascript data files](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-js/)

`_data/movies.js`:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const moviesFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, "../movies");

const movies = fs
    .readdirSync(moviesFolder)
    .filter(name => path.extname(name) === ".json")
    .map(name => ({
        key: path.parse(name).name,
        ...require(path.join(moviesFolder, name)),
    }));

module.exports = movies;
```

`movie.njk`:

```
---
pagination:
    data: "movies"
    size: 1
    alias: "movie"
permalink: "{{ movie.key }}/"
---
<h1>{{ movie.title }}</h1>
```